# How to use loc[] In python

Tags: python

For the following dataframe:

```
d = {'a':[10,11,12,13],'b':[20,21,22,23], 'c':[30,31,32,33]}
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
pd_df.set_index('a')
```

```
    b   c
a       
10  20  30
11  21  31
12  22  32
13  23  33
```

This code

```
pd_df.loc[10]
```

gives the following error:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1789                 if not ax.contains(key):
-> 1790                     error()
   1791             except TypeError as e:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in error()
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 

KeyError: 'the label [10] is not in the [index]'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You are trying to induce values out of range. If you want to get the first column use df.loc[0]

Comment: [Here is a link to the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set index to `a`, then do the following:

```
d = {'a':[10,11,12,13],'b':[20,21,22,23], 'c':[30,31,32,33]}
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
pd_df = pd_df.set_index('a')  ## <<< CHANGE HERE
```

Then

```
pd_df.loc[10]
```

Output:

```
b    20
c    30
Name: 10, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I didn't realise I forgot to save the index